# Arranging layouts inside BottomSheetDialogFragment so that all Views fit as intended

Tags: android, layout, bottom-sheet

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, which has some content and a blue button (`TextView`) on the bottom. I want it to be always anchored to the bottom of the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, yet I was unable to do so.. Most of the time it's in the right place, but sometimes it appears to be a bit below, like on this screenshot below:

[image]

How can I make sure that the blue button is always anchored to the bottom of `BottomSheetDialogFragment` no matter what? The root view is `RelativeLayout`, and when I tried setting `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've found 2 possible solutions for this problem, hence I'm sharing them here.

First solution is to make the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` expand to full screen, below is an example of how it is done:

```
View parent = (View) view.getParent();
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) (parent).getLayoutParams();
CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) behavior;
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(view.getMeasuredHeight());
```

Then, we adjust the position of the button inside the layout of our `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, for example if we have `RelativeLayout` we could set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. This would provide that our button would always be aligned at the bottom of the screen when the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is expanded (to full screen).

Another solution, which I believe is the **RIGHT SOLUTION** is to enclose all the contents of the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` layout inside a `ScrollView`. This way, if the height of the device is not sufficient, the content, including the button, will be positioned, yet could be scrolled to at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Just an hack

- Put the bottom button in your activity/ fragment (parent of Bottomsheet).
- Make it visible when bottom sheet is visible.
- Put button height equal margin on bottom of bottomsheet. (to not be overlapped by button)
- Make button invisible when bottomsheet is dismissed.

Problem solved. :)

Comment: I thought of this solution, yet then the button will not slide up together with the BottomSheet, it'll have other appearance behaviour..

Comment: I was thinking of your requirement, and I am not getting it. Because button should come up with bottomsheet opening, but should not go down with bottomsheet, how is that possible, I am confused.

Comment: It should be on the BottomSheet, yet it should be just be in the correct position on the screen when the BottomSheet is fully out.. But on the image you can see, that it's a bit below intended position.

Comment: Is it working as expected, does this float on screen till bottomsheet is opened (while opening/ closing)?

Comment: I found 2 possible solutions to my problem, I'm going with the 2nd one. I wrote them as an answer to the question. Thank you for your interest!